# I have list of webpage URLs, I just need to strip everything except specific value and ID from it using regex

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

Suppose I have list of URLs that follow structure below. I need to strip each one out so all thats left is the abcustomerid=12345. How can I do this using regex with notepad ++?

Here's an example of the different variety in each line. I just need to remove everything from each line, but leave the abcustomerid=12345 or whatever value that follows abcustomerid.

```
/the/stucture/blah.php?timeout=300&abcustomerid=53122&customer=zxyi
/some/other/struct/pagehere.php?today=Thursday&abcustomerid=241&count=54
/blah/blah/tendid.php?abcustomerid=12525
```

Each line could have anything different around the abcustomerid, but i just need to remove everything and keep the abcustomerid and the value.

Comment: Is it always `abcustomerid` that you are after? Is the value always an integer? Have you tried any regexs to accomplish this?

Comment: yes, in this case yes.

Comment: `&abcustomerid=(\d+)&` and use $1 to access the id

Comment: how about using notepad ++ to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Is that question to me? I think my regex would work in notepad++, does it not?

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do it.

```
(?:&|\?)abcustomerid=(\d+)
```

Usage:

```
<?php
$string= '/the/stucture/blah.php?timeout=300&abcustomerid=53122&customer=zxyi
/some/other/struct/pagehere.php?today=Thursday&abcustomerid=241&count=54
/blah/blah/tendid.php?abcustomerid=12525';
preg_match_all('~(?:&|\?)abcustomerid=(\d+)~', $string, $output);
print_r($output[1]);
```

The `?:` tells the regex not to capture that group. We don't want to capture that data because it is irrelevant. The `()` capture the data we are interested in. The `\d+` is one or more numbers (the `+` is the one or more part of it). If it can be any value change that to `.+?` which will match anything but then you will need an anchor for where it should stop. I'd use `(?:&|$)`, which tells it to capture until the next `&` or the end of the string if it is multilined you'll need to use the `m` modifier. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 53122
    [1] => 241
    [2] => 12525
)
```

Demo:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/37a4ddea8c50f98a41ac7d45fec98f5f1f58761f

Answer (score 1):

Here is the RegEx which takes the `abcustomerid` with its value.

```
[?&](abcustomerid=\d+)
```

However, how you are going to 'remove everything' using Notepad++?
You can use [this service](https://regex101.com) to do this (there is demo in the end of the answer).

Copy your regex and all your data into `Test string` form. After it succesfully matches everything, look at `Match information` window at the middle right of the page. Click `Export matches...` button and choose `plain text`.

You will get something like this:

```
abcustomerid=53122
abcustomerid=241
abcustomerid=12525
```

Here is the [working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fE6cK0/2).

Comment: Good usage of character class, a bit easier to read than my or's. You case use a `+` in place of `{1,}`.